# NGiNX RTMP module exec_xxx commands not working

Tags: nginx, rtmp, mpeg-dash

I a having trouble nginx 1.10.3 and rtmp module exec_xxx commands.  I have nginx.conf
with the following code.

```
rtmp {
  ...  
server {
   ...
application dash {      #creates a rtmp application
    exec_options on;
    exec_pull           /bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/conf/ping.sh pull;
    exec_push           /bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/conf/ping.sh push;
    exec_static         /bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/conf/ping.sh static;
    exec_publish        /bin/bash /usr/local/nginx/conf/ping.sh publish;
    ...
```

I can read the rtmp DASH video externally that I publish internally from local host.  So I know the conf file is working.  I can also verify the directives are active with 'sudo -i nginx -T | grep exec_'.  But the ping.sh (shown below) is not being executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ./test.txt
/bin/echo "got message 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3" 
/bin/echo "got message 1=$1 2=$2 3=$3" >>/usr/local/nginx/conf/exec_log.txt
```

The ping.sh command works when executed from  ~/nginx/. How can I tell why the exec_pull static and other 'exec_xxx' commands are not working?

Comment: Did you check permissions and all?  What does the error_log say?

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: First need to know if any error appears or it fails silently. in the case where it fails silently, most probable is that it doesn't fail, simply does what it is told while being told to do something we didn't intend to do. meaning you should retest the nginx.conf file and start from there.

Comment: Sorry  guys.  I got put on a different project. I think the problem is the SELinux but I have not been able to confirm. I am on raspian-stretch-lite  Thanks to all posters.

Comment: This question doesn't really help anyone.  Sure, what about SELinux.. We don't have insight into the runtime user of the nginx user and permissions/ownership of the scripts in question (+x ?), and the owner has abandoned the question.  No logs and no mention of running in foreground with higher verbosity output.

Comment: I cannot say I can answer the question with an exact solution, but in my case I had exactly the same behavior/issues.

I couldn't even get a bash script to write to /tmp

So I knew my recordings were happening properly so I set up a directory at the same level as the directory where my recordings were placed correctly.

I changed all of the permission bits, owner, group of this new directory to nginx to mirror my recordings directory.

Then I had nginx call my script which inside of it wrote to this new directory.  Everything worked properly.

Thus, in my case, permission bits issue